# jQuery - same function() with different elements

Tags: jquery

I am making a page with three buttons and have three different text fields. I am trying to use this function:

```
function funName() {
    $(this).show({
      'left': '-=700px'
    });
}
```

for three different `$("#IDs")`. to display different boxes of text.
Iv tried

```
$("btnElement").click(function() {
   $("#ID1").funName();
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The way to define a new jQuery method is by definining `jQuery.fn.methodName`:

```
jQuery.fn.funName = function() {
    $(this).show({
      'left': '-=700px'
    });
}
```

Comment: or pass the target element into the function: `function funName($el){ $el.show(...) }. $('bin').click(function(){ funName($('#id')) });`

Comment: @Mike That's what I was going to answer first, but I thought it would be more interesting to show how to do what he wrote.